# ImportError: cannot import name 'etree' in Visual Studio Debug console while running python file from C++

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2019

Using Embedded python with c++, I was able to call python file from C++.

Python file contains: from lxml import etree
The python file runs successfully in python3.6 IDLE.

But while running the C++ in Visual studio debugging, finding the below error in VS debug console
ImportError: cannot import name 'etree'.

How to resolve this error.
Env details:

1. VS 2019
2. Python 3.6 (x86)
3. lxml 4.6.2

Thanks in advance
**CPP code**

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    PyObject* pName{}, * pModule{}, * pDict{}, * pFunc{}, * pValue{}, * presult{};

    int data = 255;
    // Initialize the Python Interpreter
    Py_Initialize();
    // Build the name object
    pName = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"Test_lxml");

        pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    if (pModule != NULL)
    {
        data = 254;
        std::cout << "Module != NULL\n";
        pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
        pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, (char*)"verify_lxml");
        if (PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
        {
            pValue = Py_BuildValue("(z)", (char*)"1");
            PyErr_Print();
            presult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pValue);
            PyErr_Print();
        }
        else
        {
            PyErr_Print();
        }
        data = 253;
        std::string val("");
        if (presult != NULL)
        {
            presult = PyUnicode_AsUTF8String(presult);
            val = std::string(PyBytes_AsString(presult));
            data = stoi(val);

            Py_DECREF(pValue);

            // Clean up
            Py_DECREF(pModule);
            Py_DECREF(pName);
            // Finish the Python Interpreter
            Py_Finalize();
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Module end\n";
    std::cout << data;
}

**Test_lxml.py**
      
def verify_lxml(expected_string):
        import sys
        sys.path.insert(1,r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36\Lib\site-packages')
        from lxml import etree
        print(expected_string)
        return expected_string
        
def main(): 

        verify_lxml('3')        
        
if __name__ == "__main__": 

        # calling main function
        main()

**Visual Studio Debug Console**
Module != NULL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36\Lib\Test_lxml.py", line 6, in verify_lxml
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: cannot import name 'etree'
Module end
253
```

Comment: Please, show some code. Show the C++ code which you use to _"call python file from C++"_. Also, show the complete traceback which comes with the `ImportError`, as well as the Python code which causes that.

Comment: are you saying that when you run the C++ executable outside of the debugger, everything works? and when you run the same C++ code inside a debugger, then in that scenario the problem appears?  if so, it seems like the environment settings are different (possibly the PYTHONPATH)

Comment: @zvone Please find the details requested in the image attached "Import Etree Error details"

Comment: @pestophagous: Even with PYTHONPATH settings also, I facing same error

Comment: Unfortunately a screenshot is not an acceptable way to show us your code and errors. Give [this markdown editing article](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) a read, it should help you understand how to properly format your question.

Comment: @RamBalajee Here is also a nice read about [why you should not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Now added, CPP code, Test_lxml.py and VS debug console tracebacks

Comment: @zvone @ taylorthurlow. Please let me know if you any update on the issue

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Configuration must be in Release instead of Debug. Thanks for the support